# Fetch the last row of a cursor with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

On Android, I am very used to using cursor.moveToLast() to fetch the last item in a cursor. I can't seem to find an equivalent for Python's SQLite, however. Is there a function which will allow me to get the last row of a cursor?

I could just call cursor.fetchall() and get the last item in the list, but is there something more efficient than that? Thanks.

Comment: There is no 'go to last row' function, no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: This works well.  If you haven't defined a column that can be used, you can use the default undeclared column as the id. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html